# How to pass variable from pipeline to job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to create a unique identifier in a pipeline and then all jobs started from this pipeline should have access to this unique identifier.
I do not want to parameterize those jobs.

I thought that environment variable defined on a pipeline level will be accessible from jobs, but it isn't.

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   environment {
       TEST_VAR = 'TEST_VAR'
   }
   stages {
      stage('Stage1') {
         steps {
            build (job: 'job1')
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If the environment variables do not propagate to downstream jobs and you do not want to parameterize those jobs, then you may be stuck. If this pipeline job only invokes downstream jobs though, then this job may be unnecessary in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need to parameterize the downstream pipelines but can still pass the variable as a parameter from the upstream and access it in the downstream.

**Upstream pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
       TEST_VAR = 'hello_world'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build-downstream-job') {
            steps {
                build job: 'downstream-job', parameters: [string(name: 'TEST_VAR', value: env.TEST_VAR)], wait: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Downstream pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Get-test-var') {
            steps {
                println(params.TEST_VAR)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Downstream pipeline console output**

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Get-test-var)
[Pipeline] echo
hello_world
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding a '$' before TEST_VAR:

```
environment {
     TEST_VAR = '$TEST_VAR'
}
```